# i can't use static files from my Django app

Tags: django, static-files

I went to this route `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/corefiles/chatbot-data.xlsx` but i get `Page not found (404)` error...

I added those to the URLs:

```
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

File directory is `/rootproject/core/static/corefiles/testexel.xlsx`

My `settings.py` :

> STATIC_URL = '/static/'
>
> STATICFILES_DIRS = (
> normpath(join(BASE_DIR, 'static')),
> normpath(join(BASE_DIR, 'upload')), )
>
> STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'))

Answer (score 1):

Static files are to be used in your project, if you need to view a document at the specified url, you need to specify media url and media root in the settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Also add those to the URLs:

```
 + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```